# Parity Subset Sum Dynamic Programming Python Solution

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Was given this question as an assignment:
Consider the following variant of the subset sum problem. You are given positive integers
(a1, . . . , an), along with a target value `t`. You are to design an efficient algorithm that determines whether or not
there is a subset I ⊆ {1, . . . , n}, such that
(a) |I| is even, and
(b) P
i∈I
ai = t.

Your algorithm should run in time O(nt).
Note: this is the same as the usual subset sum problem, except that now, we require the cardinality of the subset to be even.

I am currently trying to apply the dynamic programming subset sum solution by tweaking the memo values to hold and object that has both an `even` subset sum boolean value, and an `odd` boolean value. I think I am getting correct answers, but I am sure there must be a more creative/efficient way to go about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does "P i∈I ai = t" mean?

Comment: I think your adaptation of the standard dynamic programming solution is the one intended by the question-setter. The computational complexity of the problem is the same as the original subset-sum problem, since you can always just add a 0 to the set and that guarantees that if there is a solution, then there's a solution of even cardinality.